# How can my Dialog class know which element of the MainWindow has called it

Tags: qt

I work with QT-Creator 4.9.1 based on Qt 5.12.3 and I am making a gui for a touch terminal. I have a stacked widget with multiple LineEdit widgets inside on different pages. The problem i have, is that my text from the keyboard should be shown inside the LineEdit of my MainWindow.

Question:

How can I determine which LineEdit called my touchkeyboard and how can i insert the pressed key inside my LineEdit in the MainWindow when my touchkeyboard dialog is modal?

Touch-Keyboard Dialog:

[image]

Example for one Stackwidget Page:

[image]

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get some help here. Trust me! It is worth the effort also for yourself.

Comment: how should I insert code if everything was created with the designer? Do you want the 1000 lines of xml?

Comment: Trust me. It's always possible. Consider to create an example app with just two buttons in the designer. That is manageable and reduces the problem. Then create a small standalone example app. I also think that it is not necessary to use the designer at all.

Comment: In this question, there is mainly no program code because I do not know any approach, since I have only been working with QT for a week. I have an alternative solution that works, but in the solution I have a lineedit in the dialog box and this is not quite what I want. So I was thinking if i ask here, anyone could give me a hint for the right solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating QLineEdit you need  set  ID , Like that

```
#include <QLineEdit>
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT      
public:
    MyLineEdit(int id = 0, QWidget* parent = nullptr);  
    int id() const;

private: 
    int m_id;   
};


MyLineEdit::MyLineEdit(int id, QWidget *parent)
    :QLineEdit (parent)
    ,m_id(id)
{   
}

int MyLineEdit::id() const
{
    return m_id;
}
```

after that in the slot you can find out through id which one QLineEdit gave the signal

```
connect(myLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(customSlot(const QString &)));
```

or also use lambda expression

```
connect(myLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,[this](const QString & txt){

   // Touch-Keyboard Dialog 

});
```